# Changes to aspx.vb file not reflected on the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made a tweak to an aspx.vb file on a test server, just a small change to a custom error message being written in the code, by making a copy of the file, changing the text and replacing the file on the server. However, the change will not reflect when I go back to the page from the browser.

I was thinking it had something to do with the file not being compiled. However, it seems as if aspx.vb file should be compiled dynamically. Is there a setting that ensures that this happens? This is a copy of the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="MyIdeaSSO.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <location path="MyIdeaSSO.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
          <add value="MyIdeaSSO.aspx" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I guess the main thing i want to know is if changes to an aspx.vb page already on a server, should need anything else for it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compile the application, .vb file update will be contained in the application's dll.

Comment: The thing is, this already exists on the server. Can I just compile the one page? I dont really know what consists of the entire application. I just know that i want to make an edit to one page. If I compile one page can I just add the new dll to the bin file? This is where I am confused. I just picked this task up as a side job at my new job. I am not a .net person, but I need to make this one tweak for now.

Comment: if you compile the project its in it will compile all the code in that project.  the dll contains code for all .vb files in the project, so there is no way to just compile that one .vb and avoid the others.  once compiled, yes you copy the dll to the bin folder, that should update the dll to the new one.